# Remove Some HTML tags with RegExp and Java

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to remove HTML tags from a String.
This is easy, I know, I did so:

```
public String removerTags(String html)  
    {  
        return html.replaceAll("\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();  
    }
```

The problem is that I do not want to remove all the tags .. I want the tag

```
<span style=\"background-color: yellow\"> (text) </ span>
```

stay intact in the string ..

I'm using this as a kind of "highlight" in the search for a web application using GWT I'm doing ...

And I need to do this, because if the search finds text that contains some HTML tag (the indexing is done by Lucene), and it is broken, the appendHTML from safeHTMLBuilder are unable to mount a String.

You can do this in a way fairly good?

Hugs.

Comment: These questions are very frequent these days. Why can't we cluster similar questions together? *#SO tip* ;)

Comment: Make sure you take entity reference values into account as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use [JSoup](http://www.jsoup.org) for this task. Regular expressions simply aren't well suited for this task imo. And with JSoup this is basically a simple, readable and easily maintainable one-liner!

Have a look at the [`JSoup.clean`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean%28java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist%29) method, and perhaps this article:

- [Sanitize Untrusted HTML](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

Comment: that will remove all my HTML tags.

Comment: Oh no... you can provide the method with a white-list of tags you don't want it to interfere with.

Comment: I just "solved" my problem, i remove the tag before do the highlight... so, after this only the correct tags appears! thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this problem using only regular expressions:

```java
public static String filterHTMLTags(String html) {

    // save valid tags:
    String striped = html.replaceAll("(?i)\\<(\\s*/?(a|h\\d|b|i|em|cite|code|strong|pre|br).*?/?)\\>", "{{$1}}");
    // remove all tags:
    striped = striped.replaceAll("\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>", " ");
    // restore valid tags:
    striped = striped.replaceAll("\\{\\{(.+?)\\}\\}", "<$1>");

    return striped;
}
```

Be sure that you don´t use "{{ ... }}" in your html content. You can change this "save sequence" easily. The valid tags are defined in the list of first replaceAll regular expression:

> (a|h\d|b|i|em|cite|code|strong|pre|br)

The "h\d" in above list means "h1, h2, ..." are valid tags.

I tested this with this code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String teste = " <b>test bold chars</b> <BR/> <div>test div</div> \n" +
            " link: <a href=\"test.html\">click here</a> <br />\n" +
            " <script>bad script</script> <notpermitted/>\n";

    System.out.println("teste: \n"+teste);
    System.out.println("\n\n\nstriped: \n"+filterHTMLTags(teste));
}
```

Bye,
Sergio Figueiredo - 
[My blog](http://sergio.figueiredo.nom.br/blog)

Answer (score 0):

A library I've used to great effect in the past is [OWASP AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_AntiSamy_Project)

This definitely allows whitelisting / blacklisting of tags. It may be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear that libary in mind next time I need to do this kind of thing.