# replaceAll("\\<.?>") vs replaceAll("<.?>")

Tags: java, regex, escaping

When using angle brackets in Java regex, what is difference between "\\<" and just "<"?

When I tested, the result was same(or I might miss some cases).

If they are same, why people add "\\" redundantly? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347632/remove-some-html-tags-with-regexp-and-java)?

Note: I'm not asking how I can remove HTML from string, so please don't recommend me like JSoup or JTidy.

Comment: [Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/963076)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The angle-bracket characters can technically be used for lookahead and lookbehind captures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), so it can make sense to quote them defensively if the pattern is adding any segments that are provided at runtime.

Comment: I don't see how this could be an issue. From your link (Java API) it looks like the only times when `<` is a special character are `\k<name>`, `(?<name>X)` and lookbehind (`(?<=X)` and `(?<!X)`). This is the only valid use of `\k`, so no ambiguity there. Any character after `(?` must be special, so no one is going to write `Pattern.compile("(?" + myString + ")")`. Perhaps some people think it's easier to use `\\<` than make absolutely sure it's unnecessary. I know I've done this in other situations.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Have you heard of injection attacks? What if `myString` is what contains the magic opening bit?

Comment: Yes I do. And I realise that `Pattern.compile("(?" + myString + ")")` is dodgy. But my point is that it's a piece of code that no one would want to use anyway, even ignoring security. To be any use, the first character of `myString` would have to be a special character. The writer of that snippet would be expecting `myString` to begin with `<`, or `=` (lookahead), or `:` (non-capturing), etc. You wouldn't want a regex with such diverse behaviour, and you wouldn't want the behaviour to be specified by the first character of `myString` in this way.